# How to build open-mpi with mingw64?

Tags: mpi, cross-compiling, openmpi, mingw-w64

I'm trying to build `open-mpi libraries` under **linux** using `mingw-w64 compilers`.

I'm searching all over the internet but i can't find a solution to my problem.

Can be done? An if yes, could everyone give me some feedback?

I'm doing the configuration like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/server/Desktop/mpi_mingw/build --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-static --disable-mpi-f77 FCFLAGS=-ffree-form LIBS=-lwinpthread-1
```

and when i do make i get some errors like:

```
../../opal/win32/win_compat.h:93:14: error: conflicting types for 'ssize_t'
```

Comment: And your problem is... ?

Comment: My problem is that i can't build the libraries using mingw compilers. I get many many errors.

Answer (score 0):

Set your include file path as `-I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include`.
remove `-I/usr/include` for avoiding conflict of header files